Why is the pattern shrinking? I've tried multiple UV configurations, is that the problem?
I'd like to get these textures right so I can bake them, but the pattern is shrinking at the lower parts of the mesh. What's going on? How do I fix it? I've used smart UV project, unwrapped, tried an add-on, tried scaling parts of the mesh in the UV editor over the texture and made seams in different spots. the only thing that looks right is when I use Camera for texture coordinates in the shader editor, but it stretches when I bake. 

Can you attach your blend file? Also, try adding seams just above where the stretching happens, and see if that improves it

Hi :). You need to keep the same Texel Density for all parts of the UV map. There are addons to help with that
